# How to check C++ lists for specific values at a specific index

Tags: c++, list, random-seed, procedural-generation

I have a list

```
list<int>generic_list;
```

I then append a random number to the list

```
rand_num = rand();
generic_list.push_front(rand_num);
```

I then check the list for if it has a value in it

```
find(generic_list.begin(), generic_list.end(), "generic string");
```

Once I have proven that it is in the list how do I find the specific index it's at?

Comment: Use the iterator returned from `find`

Comment: Why do you want an index in a list? Use an interator. Or use a vector instead of a list, which will most probably be faster, and supports indices.

Comment: Is there a reason you want the index of an iterator into a non-random-access container? You can't really do anything with it. Using the iterator is the right way to _access_ the element. (BTW, `push_front()` = _prepend_ ; `push_back()` = append)

Comment: Linked lists and indexing is a bad combination. Consider using something else. (The linked list is the most overrated data structure. Except in very rare use cases, pretty much its only usefulness lies in practicing your skills by implementing your own.)

Comment: The container you are using (`std::list`) is a poor fit for this purpose. Also, you are prepending, not appending. If you want to prepend **and** still have random access iterators that support the `-` operator (which gives you the index as a difference between the iterators from `.find()` and `.begin()`), use a `std::deque`. If you want an associative container, use a `std::map` or a `std::unordered_map`. Judging by the `.find()` with linear complexity, I think you **do** want an associative container instead. However, please do not expect to find a “generic string” in a container of `int`s.

Comment: The nature of lists is they don't really have indexes. They have iterators instead.

Comment: Don't use linked lists. Unless you know that linked list is the best data structure choice for a given algorithm, that is. It doesn't happen often.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem with [std::distance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance). This will return the number of "hops" from the begin of your list to the found item.

As you can read in the desciption of the [std::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) function, this will return an iterator to the found element. (`end()` if nothing could be found).

Then you can simply `std::distance` to show get the index.

Please see the example code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    // Define a list and populate it with some numbers
    std::list<int> myList{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    // Look for a value in the list
    std::list<int>::iterator result = std::find(myList.begin(), myList.end(), 7);

    // And, if found, calculate the index and show it on the display
    if (result != myList.end())
        std::cout << "Index: " << std::distance(myList.begin(), result) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: My program doesn't seem happy with my use of list<int>. critiquing it for not be a template but using template structure